# Editing and Refreshing Pivot Table

Tags: vba, excel, pivot-table

I need to update the selection of data values within a pivot table in VBA excel in the most simple way possible.

At present I have the ability to refresh the model as:

`Application.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Model").PivotTables("PivotTable1").RefreshTable`

but also need to be able to set the values, rows and columns in the Pivot table and update the filters.

How can this be done?

Comment: Try recording a macro (on the Developer tab) of your changing or setting the values, rows, filters and columns of your pivot table.  Then you can come back and ask specific questions about the code.  Try reading this from the help section(https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: It has been too long since I have used Excel-VBA, your answer was perfect